# Deleting values only in a Python dictionary

Tags: python

I'm trying to delete values only in a Python dictinoary.

I defined a function called remove_table as below hoping to delete only the customer's information so that I can reuse table_number for the next customer. However, my remove_table function deletes the table number as well

```
tables = {
  1: {'name': 'Jiho','vip_status': False,                                     
     'order': {'drinks': 'Orange Juice, Apple Juice',
  'food_items': 'Pancakes',
  'total': [534.50, 20.0, 5]
      } },2: {}, 3: {}, 4: {}, 5: {}, 6: {}, 7: {},}

def assign_table(table_number, name, vip_status=False):           
   tables[table_number]['name'] = name
   tables[table_number]['vip_status'] = vip_status
   tables[table_number]['order'] = {}

def remove_table(table_number):
   del tables[table_number]

remove_table(1)
print(tables)
```

> {2: {}, 3: {}, 4: {}, 5: {}, 6: {}, 7: {}}

Since the customer who used the table 1 left, I deleted the table info and tried to assign another customer to table 1 by using the assign_table function
but got an error.

```
assign_table(1,'John',True)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "script.py", line 43, in 
> assign_table(1,'John',True)
> File "script.py", line 20, in assign_table
> tables[table_number]['name'] = name
> KeyError: 1

Thanks!!

Comment: `tables[table_number] = dict()`

Comment: `tables[table_number].clear()`?

Comment: What do you mean with "can't use... again"? What happens, what should happen (edit the question to explain)?

Comment: What exactly should the dictionary look like afterwards? Why do you think you "can't" use that key again? What happens if you just insert a new value with that key?

Comment: Learn how dictionaries work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def remove_table(table_number):
    tables[table_number] = {}
```

You can set the value to be an empty dictionary.